# tmap w/ leaflet - can't get basemap to work, set zero

Tags: r, tmap

I am trying to make a map following [this guide](https://spatialanalysis.github.io/lab_tutorials/4_R_Mapping.html), and I am having some trouble trying to get a basemap underlaying the diagram.

I am using this code to make the map:

```
tm_shape(runsample) +
  tm_fill("relative_move",title="Relative Move", alpha = 0.7) + 
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, legend.outside.position = "right") + 
  tm_basemap(server="OpenStreetMap",alpha=0.5)
```

From my understanding, tm_basemap() should make this happen, but this is the result I'm getting:

[image]

I have installed and loaded leaflet. There's no error when I run it, so I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately basemaps are not supported the "plot" mode, at least in the current version (v3). In the next version, basemaps are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tmap)
library(basemaps)

## load in tmap sample data
data("NLD_muni")

## import map using the georeferenced data as the extent
bg <- basemaps::basemap_raster(ext=NLD_muni, map_service = "carto", map_type = "light")

## plot the basemap first so it shows behind the data
tm_shape(bg)+
  tm_rgb()+
tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_polygons("pop_men", alpha = 0.4)
```